# Filter for a word in message body, not in to-address?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

My e-mail address is `abc@gmail.com`. `Abc` is also a word I want to get notified about if it appears in a message. For this purpose I have created a filter where I entered `"abc"` in the field `"Has the words"`. The problem is that it triggers on the content of the message headers as well as the message body.

Is there any way to find messages that contains `abc` in the body and exclude messages that only contains `abc` in the header?

I tried this

```
(abc -(to:"abc")
```

but it only displays messages that doesn't contain `abc` in the header (which most of my messages do).

Update: `abc` is in fact a word I use for subaddressing so it is always preceded by a plus sign but Gmail doesn't seem to consider plus characters when searching. Both `abc` and `+abc` seem to return the same results. Otherwise "`e+abc`" would be unique for the message header and never occur in the body.